# Functions with two variables, implicit function second derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, special-functions

Im trying to study for an exam and I need to find exercises about calculating derivatives of functions with two variables and calculating second derivative of implicit function (the harder the better). Preferably with answers

Comment: Consider any expression involving $x$ and $y$ and make it equal to zero. Then, differentiate!